# FetchedResultsController and displaying data from 3 nested entities in one UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Could somebody explain me how can I display in one tableViewCell data from three entities connected by relationship?

I have 3 entities, let it be User, Device, and Alert. Relationships : User has many Devices and these devices have many Alerts.

In my AlertsTableViewController I want to display every alerts with user_name property which is included in User entity. 
Should I start my fetch request by setting entity for name User or Alert?.

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"????????" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


// Set the batch size to a suitable number.
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:12];



NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"created_at" ascending:NO];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = @[sortDescriptor];

[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Alerts"];

aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) 
    {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    }

return _fetchedResultsController;
```

}

My TableView methods:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"AlertsTableViewCell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
User *u = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
//I know how to display User with details of devices by looping nsset but how to display every alerts with User.name? 
for (Device *device in u.devices) {

    [cell.textLabel setText:device.someProperty];
}


return cell;
}
```

[image: datemodel]

Answer (score 0):

When you like to display `Alert`s, in most simple cases (like yours) you will set the fetch request entity to `@"Alert"`.

To select only `Alert`s that belong to a given user you will need to define a predicate for your fetch request:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"device.user = %@",<User object or User objectID>];
```

The `User` object or `objectID` will be known to you from the app user selection, or, if you have another unique identifier for each user (like the `userName` property) you could include that in your predicate:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"device.user.name = %@",userNameVariable];
```

In most cases, the LAST thing you want to do is loop over a set of `NSManagedObject`s as they will fire faults one by one and give you a really bad user experience (especially in `cellForRow...`).

Get the data you like to display before you need to supply it to the view.

**Edit:**
In that spirit, if you like to display the `someProperty` value in your `AlertsTableViewController` you should also add:

```
fetchRequest.relationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching = @[@"device"];
```

So that the `Device`  will be fetched along with `Alert` object.

Obviously, you have to change your `cellForRow...` method to accept `Alert` objects from the FRC.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work for me. Are you 100% sure that it should work? I want to display every alert from my server with details like : name, someProperty and alert_content.

Comment: This should work. What exactly "doesn't work"? If you like to display ALL the alerts (not only from a given user) you should not use any predicate.

Comment: Maybe it works but not in my case. It seems to me that I have to set User as fetch request entity instead of Alert and then in custom method configure data to display in tableViewCell. What do you think?

Comment: You must explain better what is it you are trying to accomplish. It makes much more sense that if you like to display `Alert`s you will fetch alerts. moreover, the inverse relation is to-one so the other related entities are much easier to access. And you still didn't mention what exactly didn't work ...